# Unable to connect Ganache with Truffle/Npm Dev server

Tags: npm, blockchain, ethereum, truffle, consensys-truffle

I am able to work with Truffle and Ganache-cli. Have deployed the contract and can play with that using truffle console

```
truffle(development)> 
Voting.deployed().then(function(contractInstance) 
{contractInstance.voteForCandidate('Rama').then(function(v) 
{console.log(v)})})
undefined
truffle(development)> { tx: 
'0xe4f8d00f7732c09df9e832bba0be9f37c3e2f594d3fbb8aba93fcb7faa0f441d',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: 
'0xe4f8d00f7732c09df9e832bba0be9f37c3e2f594d3fbb8aba93fcb7faa0f441d',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: 
'0x639482c03dba071973c162668903ab98fb6ba4dbd8878e15ec7539b83f0e888f',
     blockNumber: 10,
     gasUsed: 28387,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 28387,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [],
     status: '0x01',
     logsBloom: ... }
```

Now when i started a server using "npm run dev". Server started fine but is not connecting with the Blockchain

i am getting the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
```

This is my truffle.js

```
// Allows us to use ES6 in our migrations and tests.
require('babel-register')

module.exports = {
 networks: {
    development: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*', // Match any network id
      gas: 1470000

    }
  }
}
```

Can you please guide me how i can connect ?

Comment: You should try asking this in the ethereum stackexchange site.

Comment: I have asked on gitter as well. No luck so far. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If you are getting the truffle development console (since I see `truffle(development)>`)...wouldn't that mean you are using the truffle development rpc (by using `truffle develop`)? That is port 9545.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was at currentProvider, I gave the url of ganache blockchain provider and it worked.

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
console.warn("Using web3 detected from external source like Metamask")
// Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
// window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"));

  } else {
console.warn("No web3 detected. Falling back to http://localhost:8545. You should remove this fallback when you deploy live, as it's inherently insecure. Consider switching to Metamask for development. More info here: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask");
// fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }
```

Comment: This isn't the best solution. You could keep the Metamask currentProvider and just change the RPC connection setting within Metamask to connect with your localhost RPC.

Comment: Sure and i agree, can you guide me if possible how to change the RPC connection? I tried to search but not luck or maybe i am looking in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

In your `truffle.js`, change `8545` to `7545`.

**Or**, in Ganache (GUI), click the gear in the upper right corner and change the port number from `7545` to `8545`, then restart.  With ganache-cli use `-p 8545` option on startup to set 8545 as the port to listen on.

Either way, the mismatch seems to be the issue; these numbers should match.  This is a common issue.

Comment: Thanks, i tried it didn't work.

btw this my ganache-cli out put. It is listening at port 8545


Ganache CLI v6.1.0 (ganache-core: 2.1.0)
...
Mnemonic:      tent helmet chair issue cherry ring foil nominee trophy hub poem cat
Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}

Listening on localhost:8545

Comment: What is the specific code you are running (with `npm run dev`) which is producing the error? What port etc. is it connecting to? Also, have you deployed the contract using `truffle migrate`?

Comment: Yes, i did truffle migrate and i can access the contact and can call the functions using truffle console.
You can see my ganache-cli is running on localhost:8545

i am running npm run dev and server starts and listens at localhost:8080

Comment: Not sure how to connect the localhost:8080 with contract, please take a look of my truffle.js too

Thanks a lot for the reply.

Comment: I'm asking you to post the specific javascript code which is executing after you run `npm run dev` and which produces the error.  Somewhere in there you are probably creating a web3 instance and configuring it to connect to the wrong network/port.

Answer (score 0):

Change interface to 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces) in ganache settings > server.

In truffle-config.js, use provider instead of default host config:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider")

 networks: {
   development: {
    provider: () => new HDWalletProvider([
      "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY",
    ], "http://127.0.0.1:7545/"),
    port: 7545,
    network_id: "*" // Match any network id
   }
}
```